# Server Error in '/' Application (Configuration Error)

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, plesk

I;m getting this error message in my website when I try to use my website login screen.

```
An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
```

** Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line: 284 **

**Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1069.1 **

Note the following:

1. Other pages that do not require login are working fine
2. The customErrors is set to Off
3. The website is hosted through Plesk Web Host Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default IIS error page for all HTTP 500 errors.

By default IIS doesn't show real error to remote users.

If you can open this page from your server you will see actual error. I mean connect to server via RDP, open browser, open this website.

Or in Plesk 12.5 or above you can try feature **Failed Request Tracing** which generates detailed report of each error:

[image: Plesk IIS Failed Request Tracing]

[image: Windows IIS Failed Request Tracing]

Comment: Thanks for the info. I believe that feature is very helpful and might give more detailed information about the error. However, I ended up changing the hosting company due to their delay in the customer support