# Server error in '\park' application

Tags: asp.net, hosting, web-hosting, plesk, windows-hosting

I have uploaded static asp.net website using plesk panel. I have selected starting page as index.aspx.

When I run URL link, I get this error.  **this is usually a temporary error during host Name resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server**

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This is looks like your site's domain name is not resolving to IP address.

Comment: Btw, you can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205052/server-error-in-application-configuration-error